# jQuery plugin namespace for specific objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, namespaces

I'm am trying to create a jQuery plugin that will add new namespace functions to the context object(s), while maintaining full chain-ability. I'm not sure if it's possible, but here's an example of what I have so far:

```
(function ($) {
    var loadScreen = $('<div />').text('sup lol');

    $.fn.someplugin = function (args) {
        var args = args || {},
            $this = this;

        $this.append(loadScreen);

        return {
            'caption' : function (text) {
                loadScreen.text(text);
                return $this;
            }
        };
    }
})(jQuery);
```

This works fine if I do `$(document.body).someplugin().caption('hey how\'s it going?').css('background-color', '#000');`

However I also need the ability to do `$(document.body).someplugin().css('background-color', '#000').caption('hey how\'s it going?');`

Since `.someplugin()` returns it's own object, rather than a jQuery object, it does not work as expected. I also need to be able to later on access `.caption()` by `$(document.body)`. So for example if a variable is not set for the initial `$(document.body).someplugin()`. This means that somehow how `.caption()` is going to be set through `$.fn.caption = function () ...` just for the `document.body` object. This is the part which I'm not quite sure is possible. If not, then I guess I'll have to settle for requiring that a variable to be set, to maintain plugin functions chain-ability.

Here's an example code of what I expect:

```
$(document.body).someplugin().css('background-color', '#000');
$('.non-initialized').caption(); // Error, jQuery doesn't know what caption is
$(document.body).caption('done loading...');
```

Here's what I'm willing to settle for if that is not possible, or just very inefficient:

```
var $body = $(document.body).someplugin().css('background-color', '#000');
$('.non-initialized').caption(); // Error, jQuery doesn't know what caption is
$body.caption('done loading...');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The be jquery-chainable, a jQuery method MUST return a jQuery object or an object that supports all jQuery methods.  You simply have to decide whether you want your plugin to be chainable for other jQuery methods or whether you want it to return your own data.  You can't have both.  Pick one.

In your code examples, you could just define more than one plugin method, `.someplugin()` and `.caption()`.  jQuery does not have a means of implementing a jQuery plugin method that applies to one specific DOM object only.  But, there is no harm in making the method available on all jQuery objects and you can only use it for the ones that it makes sense for.

I think you could use this:

```
(function ($) {
    var loadScreen = $('<div />').text('sup lol');

    $.fn.someplugin = function (args) {
        var args = args || {},
            $this = this;

        $this.append(loadScreen);
        return(this);
    }

    $.fn.caption = function (text) {
        loadScreen.text(text);
        return this;
    }
})(jQuery);

$(document.body).someplugin().css('background-color', '#000');
$('.non-initialized').caption('whatever');
$(document.body).caption('done loading...');
```

If there's supposed to be some connection between the two `.caption()` calls, please explain that further because I don't follow that from your question.

Comment: the whole point is so that I will not clutter up the jQuery namespace, while still being able to extend chainable functions onto my own plugins. `.caption()` could be something completely different between `$.fn.loading = function () ...` and `$.fn.tabs = function ()`. Basically, I need the ability to separate `.caption()` functionality between separate plugins.

Comment: I think I've come up with a solution using `$.extend($this, {caption: function () {...}});`... It still requires that I use variables, but atleast it's not cluttering the jQuery namespace.

Comment: Keep in mind that you are extending that specific jQuery object only and you will have to save that jQuery object in order to have access to that method.  You could have also done that with `this.caption = function() {};`  You don't need `.extend()`.

Comment: so (probably an obvious question) do you think it would be more efficient to use `this.caption = function () {}` rather than extending it?

Comment: They do the exact same thing.  `.extend()` merges two objects and is useful when there are multiple properties/methods on the source object.  In your case, you only have one method that you package into a temporary object just so you can use `.extend()` so there's no advantage to using `.extend()`. The simple assignment like I recommended is more concise IMO.  Either will work.